# Writting to binary file a struct adds 0s

Tags: c, binaryfiles, bmp

I want to create a simple BMP and save it. Because I don't want to complicate things I decided to follow the example from [Example 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format) and just change the required things, like width and stuffs like that.

I save the `BMP_header` in the following struct:

```c
typedef struct{

    unsigned short file_type; // hex for "BM"
    unsigned int file_size;
    unsigned int empty_space; // empty space always 0x0
    unsigned int offset; // always 0x36000000

}BMP_header;
```

Also I have created a function that initialise one struct:

```c
BMP_header* BMP_header_init(unsigned int bmp_data){

    BMP_header* coppy = (BMP_header*)malloc(sizeof(BMP_header));

    coppy->file_type = 0x4d42;
    coppy->file_size = (54 + bmp_data) << 24;
    coppy->empty_space = 0;
    coppy->offset = 0x36000000;

    return coppy;

}
```

To write the header to a file, I have tried the traditional method

```c
fwrite(header, sizeof(*header), 1, f);
```

header being the `BMP_header_init` result. The problem is that my expected output doesn't match what I would expected, simply adding 0s for no reason.
I have tried to write every field of the field, thinking that the padding from the **unsigned short** field would be the cause.

The expected output should be, without the space:

```
42 4D 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00
```

that matches the Example 1 from wikipedia, but for some reasons I get an extra 3 pair of 0s (I now they are in hex):

```
42 4D *00 00 00* 46 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 36 00 00 00
```

The only thing I do in main is to build a struct and then write it to the file:

```c
FILE* f = fopen("img.bmp", "wb");

BMP_header* header = BMP_header_init(16); // to match the example

fwrite(header, sizeof(*header), 1, f);
```

Comment: and if you print out sizeof(BMP_Header) what does it show?

Comment: Where did you get the expected output from?

Comment: @OldProgrammer 14

Comment: @EricPostpischil I used a hex reader to view the content of the file

Comment: Why did you use `<< 24` in `(54 + bmp_data) << 24`?

Comment: @EricPostpischil the format on wikipedia seems to be LSB first and I sticked to that, maybe I understood wrong

Comment: Your C implementation already stores the least significant byte first, as evidenced by `0x4d42` produced 42 in the first byt and 4d in the second. Remove the `<< 24`.

Comment: Sitenote: You have to use `uintN_t` and `intN_t` types or check the size somehow (like `CHAR_BIT*sizeof(short)==16 && USHRT_MAX==0xFFFFU`) to be sure about their size and that there are no padding bits. But that gives you no information about endiannes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With `bmp_data` equal to 16, your expression `(54 + bmp_data) << 24` creates the value `70 << 24` = 1,174,405,120 = 46000000<sub>16</sub>. As seen from the fact that the `short` containing the value 4D42<sub>16</sub> is written to the file with the 42<sub>16</sub> byte first and then the 4D<sub>16</sub> byte, your C implementation stores the least significant byte first. So 46000000<sub>16</sub> produces bytes 00<sub>16</sub>, 00<sub>16</sub>, 00<sub>16</sub>, and 46<sub>16</sub> in the file, in that order.

There is no need for the `<< 24`. Remove it. Also change `coppy->offset = 0x36000000;` to `coppy->offset = 0x36;`.

Note that this code will not be portable, as other C implementations may store the bytes of objects in different orders.

Additionally, I would have expected a typical C implementation to insert two bytes of padding after the `unsigned short file_type` and before the `unsigned int file_size` in the structure, to keep the `unsigned int` aligned to a multiple of four bytes. It is odd that does not appear between the two members in the file.

Comment: You can use `__attribute__((packed))` to avoid padding where possible. Note that this is not possible everywhere, for example ARM can't access multibyte integer on arbitrary addresses.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123: Inability of the hardware to access multibyte integers at unaligned addresses does not prevent a C compiler from implementing packed structures. The compiler can generate byte-by-byte load and store instructions if necessary.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. But you have to take care when using pointers. Your program may cause UB when you access data in the struct via a pointer that doesn't access individual bytes.